# twilio billing different different numbers

Tags: twilio, billing

Before moving too far into a project, I'm looking to know if with my twilio account I can have two different numbers being billed separately, or if it's only able to be on one invoice. I work for a small organization in which I do bulk text messaging to make sure everyone gets updates, invites, etc. The leaders ask me for the monthly invoice and repay me for the cost. Now, I don't want them to unknowingly be paying for my private project. If I was to purchase a second number, could it be billed separately so that invoices could be separately?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only if that is under a completely different Twilio Project.